# Print a json structure from a dynamic query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to create function that return a CLOB with a json content.

But first i want to print the result (see query code) to see how it looks like.

The result must be a json, that will contain the information for 1 record just, this record select query, must be created dynamically.

So I try the next query, to resolve this problem. but i get an error.

Query

```
declare
    v_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
    l_sep varchar2(1) := chr(10);
    l_tab varchar2(1) := chr(9);
    up_column VARCHAR2(50);
    low_column VARCHAR2(50);
    cur_asc SYS_REFCURSOR;
    Vcdogcur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    id_ccd number;
    first boolean := true;
begin
    id_ccd := 174;
    v_stmt := 'select ';

    open cur_asc for 
        SELECT column_name as up_column
              ,lower(column_name) as low_column
        FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
        WHERE table_name = upper('my_table');
    loop 
        FETCH cur_asc
        INTO  up_column, low_column;
        EXIT WHEN cur_asc%NOTFOUND;
        if not first then
            v_stmt := v_stmt || ',';
        end if;
        first := false;
        v_stmt := v_stmt || l_sep || l_tab ||up_column || ' as ' || low_column;
    END LOOP;
    --v_stmt := v_stmt || l_sep || 'from my_table' || l_sep ||'where id = ' || id_ccd || ';';
    v_stmt := v_stmt || l_sep || 'from my_table' || l_sep ||'where id = ' || id_ccd;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('salida: ' || v_stmt);
    CLOSE cur_asc;

    --v_stmt := v_stmt || l_sep || 'from my_table' || l_sep ||'where id = ' || id_ccd;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('salida: ' || v_stmt);

    open Vcdogcur for v_stmt;
        APEX_JSON.initialize_clob_output;
        APEX_JSON.open_object;
        APEX_JSON.write('my_table', Vcdogcur);
        APEX_JSON.close_object;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(APEX_JSON.get_clob_output);
    CLOSE Vcdogcur;
end;
/
```

DBMS output

```
salida: select 
    CREATED as created,
    CREATED_BY as created_by,
    UPDATED as updated,
    UPDATED_BY as updated_by,
    ID as id,
    TEXT as text,
    PART as part,
    CODE as code,
    DATE as date,
    PERCENTAGE as percentage
from my_table
where id = 174
{
"my_table":[
{
"CREATED":"2020-06-04T08:10:09.000000000Z"
,"CREATED_BY":"APEX_APP"
,"UPDATED":"2020-06-04T10:10:09.295632000Z"
,"UPDATED_BY":"APEX_APP"
,"ID":174
,"TEXT":"ALL"
,"PART":2770
,"CODE":2212
,"DATE":"2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z"
,"PERCENTAGE":-4.98
}
]
}
```

Error

```
Informe de error -
ORA-01001: cursor no válido
ORA-06512: en línea 44
01001. 00000 -  "invalid cursor"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can somebody help me to resolve this?

Best Regards

Comment: Comment out after  `CLOSE cur_asc;` and run the pl/sql block,dbms_output prints this statement `salida: select from table_name where id = 174` . Your v_stmt is malformed ,work on that.

Comment: yes, i got you, but i don't want to see the query, i want to see the json result, from APEX_JSON.get_clob_output, something like:

{"table_name":[{"CREATED":"2020-06-04T08:10:09.000000000Z","CREATED_BY":"APEX_APP","UPDATED":"2020-06-04T10:10:09.295632000Z","UPDATED_BY":"APEX_APP","ID":174,"TEXT":"ALL","PART":2770,"code":2212,"DATE":"2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z","PERCENTAGE":-4.98}]}

i'll modify my question, because i have another type of error

Comment: Unless you fix `v_stmt` you are not gonna see json result because `Vcdogcur` is based on `v_stmt`

Comment: i update the question, and you can see that dbms output ... show the query correct, and also --> open Vcdogcur for v_stmt; is working , beause i see the json result. The problem now is i got another error.

Comment: if I comment --> CLOSE Vcdogcur;

i don't see error, i could say that it works. But is it ok? don't close the cursor?
thanks

Comment: Yes comment out that line.

Comment: Add the line `APEX_JSON.free_output` to free up the clob

Comment: It looks like running ```apex_json.write``` with cursor parameter does close the cursor. This is never documented, so removing ```close``` on the cursor will solve the error.